# Will leads from a Source DE that is overwritten daily by an automation enter a 2nd version of a journey, when both has no re-entryå

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio

we have a welcome journey, where the source DE is being overwritten daily. It has no re-entry setting on. Now I want to make changes to this journey by creating a second version. Will all the leads from this DE re-enter the 2nd version ( given I have no re-entry again). or because it's basically the same journey, they won't enter again?

Comment: No, the same records will not enter again

Comment: thanks a lit Swati!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this help doc: [Journey Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_settings.htm&type=5)

TL;DR No-rentry is for the Journey, not a Version

> Select No re-entry if contacts can’t enter the journey again after a previous entry. For example, in a Welcome Journey, set your entry to No re-entry because you want your customers to be introduced to your brand only one time. This setting applies across all versions of a journey. After you activate the journey, you can’t change this option.

> NOTE Test Mode doesn’t support this setting. When testing a journey, use Re-entry at any time or Re-entry only after exiting. Then, select No re-entry after testing if necessary.